# looping over data needing to display vertical columns for 3 years only showing months that contain data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If every month of the past 3 years contained data, then this working example fiddle is how I need the data to look

https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/ncqn0jwy/

HOWEVER, I don't always have data in a given month and thus i am to not show the month if it contains no data

This is a fiddle of me trying to loop over the data

https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/2zkhk3dt/1/

I am first trying to loop over the years to get distinct years,

```
for (var y in data) {
   if (typeof(uniqueYears[data[y].year]) === "undefined") {
     distinctYears.push(data[y].year);

      year = data[y].year;
        if (year === "" || year === null) {
           year = "";
        }

     strResult += "<th style='text-align:left;'><h2>" + year + "</h2></th>";
     //console.log(year);


     uniqueYears[data[y].year] = 0;


   }
}
```

Then I loop over the months and I pay attention to the loop of the years , but I realized that this is not right at all since every row needs to be taking into consideration the year and month ,

So the data object "data" contains the data, but I'm not understanding how to mesh my data (2nd fiddle) into the year/month fiddle (1st fiddle)

I did even try to do a call into a function that loops over all my data with each of the outputs for the year month fiddle, but It seems to only show August 2015 for some reason and I did a ton of console.log

**Update**

Essentially the first fiddle is like this

(however, my data only has files in a folder for 4 months in 2015)  thus those would appear but the others I would show as blank ""  )

[image]

Update 2:

So the output of my data with my year and month loops are clearly not right at all see pic
[image]

**Update 3**

Third fiddle shows that I create a function to call into and loop over my data to be checking if the data matches up ,  sadly it is only returning August 2015  on a match

https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/rsu7mxbm/

Comment: What is the problem? I do see all months get print out.

Comment: @Brian Do you want month that does not contain data to be shown as well along with months containing data?

Comment: @imnancysun  the first fiddle is an example of me looping over months of just objects and showing the output,   I don't know if I can use those loops inside or outside of the 2nd fiddle which is the fiddle that contains my data which only has the 4 months in 2015

Comment: @pratikwebdev      Yes,  I only want to show the month if it is found in my data.   It needs to appear in the proper row , with just blanks "" for the months that are not in my data   ( months and years  )

Comment: I'm adding a 3rd fiddle that shows where I make a function call to try and get every loop to call into a function with the data object and loop over all the data ,  August of 2015 is the only one that shows up    https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/rsu7mxbm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through all 12 months and only add a link to those that appear in data, see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zkhk3dt/3/)

```
        var months = [
          { number: '01', title: 'January' },
          { number: '02', title: 'February' },
          { number: '03', title: 'March' },
          { number: '04', title: 'April' },
          { number: '05', title: 'May' },
          { number: '06', title: 'June' },
          { number: '07', title: 'July' },
          { number: '08', title: 'August' },
          { number: '09', title: 'September' },
          { number: '10', title: 'October' },
          { number: '11', title: 'November' },
          { number: '12', title: 'December' }
        ];

var data = [{
  "fileName": "August.20.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "609 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-03T07:21:11.767626-07:00",
  "directoryName": "08 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "August",
  "shortMonth": "08"
}, {
  "fileName": "September.15.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "806 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-10-21T13:18:21.577097-07:00",
  "directoryName": "09 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "September",
  "shortMonth": "09"
}, {
  "fileName": "October.22.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "331 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-15T10:21:00.194822-07:00",
  "directoryName": "10 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "October",
  "shortMonth": "10"
}, {
  "fileName": "October.28.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "2009 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-01T10:44:27.754937-07:00",
  "directoryName": "10 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "October",
  "shortMonth": "10"
}, {
  "fileName": "October.06.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "3161 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-11-25T13:51:46.210558-07:00",
  "directoryName": "10 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "October",
  "shortMonth": "10"
}, {
  "fileName": "December.03.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "1778 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-07T05:23:33.228568-07:00",
  "directoryName": "12 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "December",
  "shortMonth": "12"
}, {
  "fileName": "December.04.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "144 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-08T05:06:34.223478-07:00",
  "directoryName": "12 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "December",
  "shortMonth": "12"
}, {
  "fileName": "December.07.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "201 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-09T05:04:58.541633-07:00",
  "directoryName": "12 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "December",
  "shortMonth": "12"
}, {
  "fileName": "December.09.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "170 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-10T05:03:51.05038-07:00",
  "directoryName": "12 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "December",
  "shortMonth": "12"
}, {
  "fileName": "December.21.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "1922 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-22T05:23:42.132732-07:00",
  "directoryName": "12 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "December",
  "shortMonth": "12"
}, {
  "fileName": "December.22.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "202 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-23T06:28:09.500499-07:00",
  "directoryName": "12 - 2015",
  "year": "2015",
  "month": "December",
  "shortMonth": "12"
}, {
  "fileName": "August.20.2015.pdf",
  "fileSizeText": "609 KB",
  "fileAccessed": "2015-12-03T07:21:11.78063-07:00",
  "directoryName": "01 - 2016",
  "year": "2016",
  "month": "January",
  "shortMonth": "01"
}];

var strResult = "";
var month = "";

var final = "";

strResult = "<table class='table-light' id='myTableId'><thead>";

var year = "";
var uniqueYears = {};
var distinctYears = [];

var unique = {};
var distinct = [];

var count = 0;

strResult += "<tr>";

for (var y in data) {
  if (typeof(uniqueYears[data[y].year]) === "undefined") {
    distinctYears.push(data[y].year);

    year = data[y].year;
    if (year === "" || year === null) {
      year = "";
    }

    strResult += "<th style='text-align:left;'><h2>" + year + "</h2></th>";
    //console.log(year);


    uniqueYears[data[y].year] = 0;


  }
}
strResult += "</tr></thead><tbody>";


////////////////////////////////////////
// loop over the years 
for (var z in distinctYears) {

  //strResult += "<th style='text-align:left;'><h2>" + distinctYears[z] + "</h2></th>";
  // loop over all the files 
  for (var i in data) {

    // create rows of the files  that match the year 
    if (distinctYears[z] == data[i].year) {



      if (typeof(unique[data[i].shortMonth]) === "undefined") {
        distinct.push({'month':data[i].shortMonth, 'year':data[i].year});
        //   do the work here
        month = data[i].month; console.log(month)
        if (month === "" || month === null) {
          month = "";
        }

      }
      unique[data[i].shortMonth] = 0;
    }

  }

}
console.log(distinct);

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
strResult += "<tr>";
  for (var z in distinctYears)
  {

    if (findData(months[i], distinctYears[z]))
        {
           if (z == 0) {
          strResult += "<td><a target='blank' class='link ng-binding' href='files.html?id=sub&year=" + distinctYears[z] + "&month=" + months[i].number + "' onclick=\"getFiles('" + distinctYears[z] + "','" + months[i].number + "');\">" + months[i].title + "</a></td>";
        } else if (z == 1) {
          strResult += "<td><a target='blank' class='link ng-binding' href='files.html?id=sub&year=" + distinctYears[z] + "&month=" + months[i].number + "' onclick=\"getFiles('" + distinctYears[z] + "','" + months[i].number + "');\">" + months[i].title + "</a></td>";
        } else if (z == 2) {
          strResult += "<td><a target='blank' class='link ng-binding' href='files.html?id=sub&year=" + distinctYears[z] + "&month=" + months[i].number + "' onclick=\"getFiles('" + distinctYears[z] + "','" + months[i].number + "');\">" + months[i].title + "</a></td>";
        }     
      }
  else
  {
           if (z == 0) {
          strResult += "<td>"+months[i].title + "</td></td>";
        } else if (z == 1) {
          strResult += "<td>" + months[i].title + "</td>";
        } else if (z == 2) {
          strResult += "<td>" + months[i].title + "</td>";
        }  
  }


    }
      strResult += "</tr>";
}

function findData(m, y)
{
  for (var z in distinct)
    {
       if (distinct[z].month == m.number && distinct[z].year == y)
         return true;
    }
  return false;  
}

strResult += "</tbody></table>";
$("#divResult").html(strResult);
```

Comment: Sweet,   this is looking much better!   What about that I want to actually skip 2016  and ONLY show 3 columns with all the month rows,   so  2015, 2014 , 2013     ( obviously nothing would display for 2014  and 2013 ...

Comment: Add those years to array distinctYears

Comment: Ok,  i think this is what i want  https://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/1rs87ac8/1/      , does that seem right to you?      ( I don't want to display any 2016 yet,  and then I will end up not showing the months that do not have any data